# Button being pushed down by a transition

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-transitions

I'm having trouble with two list items that have a transition applied to them. When you hover over one of them, it expands to reveal some more information, but pushes the other item down.

This only happens when `overflow:hidden` is added. Remove that and everything acts as expected. Here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0g9mttdm/1/ Thanks.

```css
.homepage-buttons {
  width: 100%;
  margin: -100px 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.homepage-buttons ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.homepage-buttons ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 -2px;
  border: 1px solid #9DBC43;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 25%;
  height: 170px;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width 1s, height 1s linear 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.homepage-buttons ul li:hover {
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
}

.fa-users,
.fa-briefcase {
  color: #9DBC43;
}

.btn-circle.btn-xl {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-size: 28px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.btn-default {
  background-color: #4E545F;
  border: 10px solid #9DBC43;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-default:hover {
  background-color: #4A6400;
  border: 10px solid #4A6400;
  color: #fff;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: #4E545F;
  border: 10px solid #9DBC43;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  background-color: #004435;
  border: 10px solid #004435;
  color: #fff;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="homepage-buttons">
  <ul>
    <li><button class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl" type="button"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><br />
      <h4>Personal</h4>
      <h5>Hello there</h5>
    </li>
    <li><button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-xl" type="button"><i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><br />
      <h4>Corporate</h4>
      <h5>Hello there</h5>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you the `li`s are `inline-block` and `vertical-align` is `baseline` by default.

Change to `vertical-align: top` and you are done - see demo below:

```css
.homepage-buttons {
  width: 100%;
  margin: -100px 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.homepage-buttons ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.homepage-buttons ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 -2px;
  border: 1px solid #9DBC43;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 25%;
  height: 170px;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width 1s, height 1s linear 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.homepage-buttons ul li:hover {
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
}

.fa-users,
.fa-briefcase {
  color: #9DBC43;
}

.btn-circle.btn-xl {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-size: 28px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.btn-default {
  background-color: #4E545F;
  border: 10px solid #9DBC43;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-default:hover {
  background-color: #4A6400;
  border: 10px solid #4A6400;
  color: #fff;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: #4E545F;
  border: 10px solid #9DBC43;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  background-color: #004435;
  border: 10px solid #004435;
  color: #fff;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="homepage-buttons">
  <ul>
    <li><button class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl" type="button"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><br />
      <h4>Personal</h4>
      <h5>Hello there</h5>
    </li>
    <li><button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-xl" type="button"><i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><br />
      <h4>Corporate</h4>
      <h5>Hello there</h5>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Fixed it!

Comment: I actually have a follow-up question. Is that allowed? How would I change the direction of the height expansion? At the moment the hidden content is revealed below, but what if I wanted the hidden content to behind the button, which would expand upwards to reveal the hidden content?

Comment: well, if you are using `display: inline-block` I guess you possibly can't get it to expand upwards, maybe you can try `positioning` (using `relative` and `absolute` of the `div` and `ul`)... try it out and let me know if you are stuck... will help you with it...